# Visualizing the correspondence between linear maps and matrices as a natural isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

I was trying to interpret the equivalence between linear maps on finite dimensional vector spaces and matrices in a categorical POV. The idea is to capture the following: given a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$ and fixed bases $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ on $V$ and $W$ respectively, there is a matrix $A \in M_{n\times n}
(K)$ s.t.

$$(T(x))_{\beta_2}
=A_{\beta_1, \beta_2} .x_{\beta_1}$$

for all $x \in V$.

It seems to me that this property can be represented by a natural transformation, but the fact that we (probably) must encode the bases in the objects or morphisms of the categories is confusing me as to how to produce categories and functors to give rise to my interpretation.

My question, summarized, is:

**Is there a way to make the equation described to correspond to a natural transformation between suitable functors?**

If the question is unclear, please say so and I'll try to elaborate further.

EDIT: Although I've accepted an answer which "denies" my question, investigating further I've arrived at the fact that this is indeed involves a natural transformation. The natural transformation is the sending of the ordered basis to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{K}^n$, and the functors are the identity functor and the functor described on the answer. The category is the category for which the objects are the vector spaces with a chosen ordered basis.

Comment: Because you need to choose bases, there shouldn't actually be a natural isomorphism, I would think. The situation is different in the category of objects of the form $\mathbb{K}^n$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is our underlying field, because every vector space there has a canonical basis.

Comment: @StefanPerko Yes. That is what I thought about when I said that you "must encode the bases..." somehow. I think that just managing objects/morphisms as vector spaces alone (or $K^n$ alone) should not be expected to yield fruitful things. But if you manage to encode the bases... it seems to me that a natural isomorphism can be on sight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a category whose objects are pairs $(V, B)$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and a basis $B$ of it, and whose morphisms $(V, B) \to (W, C)$ are linear transformations $f : V \to W$. This category is (very canonically) equivalent to the "matrix category" whose objects are the vector spaces $K^n$ and whose morphisms are linear maps $K^n \to K^m$, with the equivalence given on objects by expressing $v \in V$ in terms of the basis $B$ and given on morphisms by expressing a linear transformation $T : V \to W$ in terms of the bases $B$ and $C$. So you're looking for a functor, not a natural transformation.

Comment: And of course, both of these categories are equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces; there's just no canonical choice for the functor going in one direction of the equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've accepted an answer which "denies" my question, investigating further I've arrived at the fact that this is indeed involves a natural transformation. The natural transformation is the sending of the ordered basis to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{K}^n$, and the functors are the identity functor and the functor described on the answer. The category is the category for which the objects are the vector spaces with a chosen ordered basis.